# Regex - disect a expression into bits in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to disect a certain expression:

```
column_count:[dropdown]:[2:3:4:6]:[3]
```

There are 4 parts I need to read out:

```
1. column_count -> no brackets (using preg_split?)
2. [dropdown]:[2:3:4:6]:[3] -> into 3 parts of "brackets insides"
3. [2:3:4:6] -> this third part needs further disection into 4 different values
```

So my output would be:

```
1. string: column_count
2. array([dropdown], [2:3:4:6], [3])
3. array(2, 3, 4, 6)
```

I guess I need 3 different regular expressions for it, but I am still new with them and I have no idea how to approach these steps.

Any explanation or tip is welcome, I would like to learn it.

Comment: to get first and two `preg_split('~:~', $str, 2)`

Comment: with regex, best is to just follow tutorial(s), until you know it all. it is really not so much.. can be learned in a day or two, easily. it will make your future life a lot easier/less frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more easy seems to me to describe the full string with more or less details (depending the possible formats) and to use capture groups to isolate main parts separated by semi-colons. Once you do that you only need to use basic manipulations to obtain the items you want:

```
$str = 'column_count:[dropdown]:[2:3:4:6]:[3]';

$pattern = '~^([^:]+):(\[[^]]*]):(\[[^]]*]):(.*)$~'; 

if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $m))
    $result = [
        $m[1],
        [ $m[2], $m[3], $m[4] ],
        explode(':', trim($m[3], '[]'))
    ];

var_dump($result);
```

Note that the pattern mainly uses the negated character class `[^...]` to stop the greedy quantifiers.

An other way without regex:

The idea is to transform the string to a csv line. To do it all `[` and `]` are translated to `"[` and `]"` with [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), and the double quote is defined as the enclosure parameter for [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php). In this way, colons between square brackets are ignored by the parser (since they are now between double quotes).

```
$p = str_getcsv(strtr($str, ['['=>'"[', ']'=>']"']), ':', '"');

$result2 = [
    $p[0],
    [ $p[1], $p[2], $p[3] ],
    explode(':', trim($p[2], '[]'))
];

var_dump($result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `preg_split` and regex `"/:(?=\[)/"`, it should give you an array like `array( 'column_count1', '[dropdown]', '[2:3:4:6]', '[3]' )`. For the last part you can use `preg_match_all` and regex `\d` ( or `\d+` ).

The `(?=\[)` part in regex is [lookahead for positive assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Comment: Thank you, with your link I understand regex's a lot better now!